# zip_open(); undefined on PHP 5.2.8

Tags: php, zip

I've done a bit of searching around and was unsuccessful in finding an ample solution.

Specs are: OS X 10.5 with Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.7l DAV/2 PHP/5.2.8

Error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function zip_open() in /includes/admin_functions.php on line 18

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your phpinfo();

The only reason the function would be undefined is if the extension was not properly installed.  Ensure that it appears when you run your phpinfo() page.

Comment: I don't really know how to tell but from my understanding its gzip and it's showing up on here. 

My php info can be seen here
http://freetexthost.com/vx5ugpgtyu

On a side note, To install all that is needed is to remove the comment under my php.ini & restart my server... correect?

Thank you

Comment: You can contact your host for help.  It requires the library to actually be installed on the server, just enabling it in php.ini does not necessarily mean it is installed.  Gzip is different from the Zzip library.  You can use the gzip functions to do .gz compression if you would like.

Comment: how to check in phpinfo

Answer (score 5):

your zip module is not configured properly or missing

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the [ZIP module](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) installed?

Comment: Yes, I just installed it and it keeps spitting out these errors